# How to get the users MFA (MultiFactor Authentication) status from api?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there an api to get the user's mfa status?

I checked the /users/xxxx api and user profile api, didn't find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the 2FA status for a DocuSign user is currently available from a public API. I have filed DocuSign internal enhancement request TRI-19164 about this.

Please ask your DocuSign support or sales contact to add your organization's information to the ticket. Thank you.